# How to mock `name` attribute with unittest.mock.MagicMock or Mock classes?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to create MagicMock with mocked name and it seems as not working, but works for other attributes:

```py
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

# Works
assert MagicMock(foo='bar').foo == 'bar'

# Don't work
assert MagicMock(name='bar').name == 'bar'

print(MagicMock(name='bar').name)
<MagicMock name=\'bar.name\' id=\'140031146167376\'>
```

How to mock name attribute with MagicMock ?

Answer (score 30):

The name attribute cannot be mocked during creation of the mock object, since it has special meaning:

> name: If the mock has a name then it will be used in the repr of the mock. This can be useful for debugging. The name is propagated to child mocks.

[Python Documentation of Mock](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock)

Therefore in order to mock the name it shall be set after creating the Mock or MagicMock object and before passing it forward:

```
mock_obj = MagicMock()
mock_obj.name = 'bar'

assert mock_obj.name == 'bar'

# Passing mock object forward
...
```

Answer (score 7):

It's been a while since this question was asked, but the [mock's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-names-and-the-name-attribute) now mentions this case explicitly and suggests two solutions. One of them is to set the `name` attribute after mock creation, as [shown in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62552149/4744341); another possible solution is to use [`configure_mock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.configure_mock):

```
>>> mock = MagicMock()
>>> mock.configure_mock(name='my_name')
>>> mock.name
'my_name'
```

Comment: Would be nice if configure_mock, would return itself, so it can be ONE line, rather than two...